# Guardar foto en directorio

Tags: android

Al hacer clic en un Item de mi `ListView` abre la camara, pero al tomar la foto no me la guarda en el directorio que estoy creando.

El directorio que estoy creando no existe en el momento que la guardo, que estoy haciendo mal?

```
public class ListaConImag extends AppCompatActivity {

miAdaptador adaptador;
ArrayList<ContenidoVista> datos;
android.widget.ListView lista;
String ANDROID_DATA = "Android/data";
String dirCarpetaImg;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_con_imag);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    lista = (android.widget.ListView) findViewById(R.id.Lista_imag);
    datos = new ArrayList<ContenidoVista>();
    rellenardatos();
    adaptador = new miAdaptador(this, datos);
    lista.setAdapter(adaptador);


    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Animation rotar = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.girar);
            Animation zoom = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.zoom);
            Animation trasparencia = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.trasparencia);
            Animation mover = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.mover);
            switch (position){

                case(0):
                    view.findViewById(R.id.icono).startAnimation(rotar);
                    Intent IntCamara = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    dirCarpetaImg = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ ANDROID_DATA+"/com.appjor/";
                    File carpetaImagen = new File(dirCarpetaImg);
                    if(!carpetaImagen.exists()){ //Existe el directorio?
                        carpetaImagen.mkdirs(); // si no existe, lo crea.
                    }
                    File imagenApp = new File(carpetaImagen,"foto.jpg");
                    Uri dirImagen = Uri.fromFile(imagenApp);
                    IntCamara.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, dirImagen);
                    startActivityForResult(IntCamara, 1);


                break;

                case(1):

                    break;

                case(2):
                    view.findViewById(R.id.icono).startAnimation(trasparencia);
                    break;

                case(3):
                    view.findViewById(R.id.icono).startAnimation(mover);
                    break;
            }
        }


    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

      }

    }


private void rellenardatos() {

    datos.add(new ContenidoVista("CAMARA", "Iniciar camara", R.drawable.perro));
    datos.add(new ContenidoVista("INFORMACION", "Mostar informacion", R.drawable.perro1));
    datos.add(new ContenidoVista("Titulo3", "SubTitulo3", R.drawable.perro2));
    datos.add(new ContenidoVista("Titulo4", "SubTitulo4", R.drawable.persona));
     }

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que el directorio `/imagenesApp` no existe,

```
 Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+
                                                   "/imagenesApp/"+"foto.jpg");
```

lo que se realiza regularmente es validar, si no existe se crea.

```
String ANDROID_DATA = "/Android/data/";
String externalDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +  ANDROID_DATA + "/imagenesApp/";

        File carpetaImgen = new File(externalDir);
                if(!carpetaImgen.exists()){ //Existe el directorio?
                    carpetaImgen.mkdirs(); // si no existe, lo crea.            
                }
```

Comment: no lo estoy creando en `File carpetaImgen = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"imagenesApp");
                    carpetaImgen.mkdirs()` ?

Comment: concatena String ANDROID_DATA = "/Android/data/"; a Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() ve mi respuesta.

Comment: Sigo teniendo el mismo problema, solo que ahora no me tira ninguna Exepcion

Comment: agrega Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() , Puedes imprimir el valor de externalDir  por favor ?

Comment: La direccion es : /storage/emulated/0Android/data/com.appjor/

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podrias tener problemas con el AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
```